# Resizable Div using vue-resizable

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to build a resizable component using [vue-resizable](https://github.com/nikitasnv/vue-resizable) and everything works fine except when I try to update the component size using percentage value by selecting it from a dropdown box. The state updates correctly but no change in size takes place of the component.

**resizableContainer.vue**

```
<template>
  <vue-resizable 
    :min-width="320"
    :width="containerWidth + '%'" 
    :active="['r']"
    
  >
    <div class="resizable-content">
      <pre>{{ containerWidth }}</pre>

      <select v-model="containerWidth">
        <option :value="75">75%</option>
        <option :value="50">50%</option>
      </select>

      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </vue-resizable>
</template>

<script>
import VueResizable from 'vue-resizable'

export default ({
  name: 'resizeableContainer',
  components: {VueResizable},
  props: ['width'],
  data () {
    return {
      containerWidth: this.width
    }
  }
})
</script>

<style scoped>
  .resizable-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: aqua;
  }
</style>
```

And am using the above component as follows:

```
<resizableContainer :width="100">
    Card 1
</resizableContainer>
```

Comment: I read the source code, I don't think it is possible. The closest one is to calculate the width by yourself but still the div will not adjust itself when screen is resized.  You can do it by listening resize event and I will leave it for you to do it. https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-brattain-mdlsq?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Comment: The percentage value works on the initial mount. After that if we change the value nothing takes effect.

Comment: Yes. so as i said you can do it by listening resize event and change the value of resizeableWidth.